# Finding BizTalk 2006 installation folder

Tags: powershell, biztalk

Is there any way to find out where Biztalk is installed on a machine using a PowerShell script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work, I think:

```
(Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\BizTalk Server\3.0\').InstallPath
```

Comment: That was 
(Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\BizTalk Server\3.0\').InstallPath 

Thank you!

Comment: Duh, yeah you're right; messed it up when copying it by hand from my VM (silly clipboard integration fails all the time!)

Comment: Works for later version of BizTalk as well. Just tried it with BizTalk 2013 R2